# SQL not updating in if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to insert or update data from form using SQL but I've get an error "Incorect syntax near ')'. Incorect syntax near the key word 'else'"

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableName
    WHERE ID = ID_from_form_field
)
    UPDATE TableName
      SET
          Name = 'Name_from_form_field',
          UniqueNumber = uniquenumber_from_form_field
    WHERE ID = ID_from_form_field;
    ELSE
INSERT INTO TableName
(Name,
 UniqueNumber
)
VALUES
('Name_from_form_field',
 uniquenumber_from_form_field
);
```

Comment: use `begin` &  `end`

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. I suspect `ID_from_form_field` has some bad data..

Comment: if
begin 
 all under if
end
gave mi "Incorect syntax near the key word 'else'" 
if I put every section between begin & and that causing error with duplicated unique number

Comment: Use BEGIN and END after if and else

Comment: @liquid begin/end is not your problem - nor is it found in the code you posted - as already suggested. Learn to debug your code. First step - stop assuming you know where the syntax problem is. Simply comment out your entire script (except variable declarations) and then uncomment each statement one by one and execute each iteration. Since you obfuscated your code, perhaps your changes have removed the actual error - impossible to see by others.

Comment: You had right SMor. ID_from_form_field was empty without value. I just set default value as 0 and it works. That field is hidden so it's not problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have problems with code before this.  But for such code, use semicolons and `begin`/`end` blocks:

```
if exists (select 1 from TableName where ID = ID_from_form_field)
begin
    update TableName
       set Name = 'Name_from_form_field',
           UniqueNumber = uniquenumber_from_form_field
       where ID = ID_from_form_field;
end;
else
begin
   insert into TableName (Name, UniqueNumber)
       values ('Name_from_form_field', uniquenumber_from_form_field);
end;
```

Comment: Than I get an error "Incorect syntax near ')'. "Incorect syntax near '='.. Both ID in db and ID_field are int.

Comment: @liquid . . . The problem is likely to be before this code.

Comment: Thank You all. Code was good just ID_from_form_field was empty field that is why code didn't work. I set ID_from_form_field = 0 as default and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `begin` & `end` it just like  `{` and `}` in C/++/# etc.

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableName
    WHERE ID = ID_from_form_field
)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TableName
          SET
              Name = 'Name_from_form_field',
              UniqueNumber = uniquenumber_from_form_field
        WHERE ID = ID_from_form_field;
END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TableName
        (Name,
         UniqueNumber
        )
        VALUES
        ('Name_from_form_field',
         uniquenumber_from_form_field
        );
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add Begin and End

```
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
          FROM   tablename 
          WHERE  id = id_from_form_field) 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE tablename 
      SET    NAME = 'Name_from_form_field', 
             uniquenumber = uniquenumber_from_form_field 
      WHERE  id = id_from_form_field 
  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO tablename 
                  (NAME, 
                   uniquenumber) 
      VALUES      ('Name_from_form_field', 
                   uniquenumber_from_form_field) 
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your query as below . You missed to add BEGIN and END after if and else for SQL Server query

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableName
    WHERE ID = ID_from_form_field
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE TableName
    SET
    Name = 'Name_from_form_field',
    UniqueNumber = uniquenumber_from_form_field
    WHERE ID = ID_from_form_field;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableName
    (Name,
    UniqueNumber
    )
    VALUES
    ('Name_from_form_field',
    uniquenumber_from_form_field
    );
END
```